# How to Authenticate Podio in C#

Tags: c#, podio

This is my first time trying to authenticate and I can't quite get it. I am working in Visual Basic and I have installed Nuget Podio.Async.

In the code below won't authenticate with app or password.

When I remove 'async' and 'await' it seems to authenticate but then I lose 'item.Fields'.

```
        static void Main()
        {
            Init();
        }

        public static async void Init()
        {
            var podio = new Podio(clientId, clientSecret);
            Console.WriteLine("Client ID and Secret");

            //await podio.AuthenticateWithApp(appId, appToken);
            await podio.AuthenticateWithPassword(username, password);
            Console.WriteLine("Authenticated");

            var item = await podio.ItemService.GetItem(1124848809);
            Console.WriteLine(item.Fields.Count);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `Init` is an `async` method. You are calling it inside a sync method (`main'). This is the wrong way to calling async method!

Please try workaround below and It should solve your problems:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Init().Wait();
    }

    public static async Task Init()
    {
        var podio = new Podio(clientId, clientSecret);
        Console.WriteLine("Client ID and Secret");

        //await podio.AuthenticateWithApp(appId, appToken);
        await podio.AuthenticateWithPassword(username, password);
        Console.WriteLine("Authenticated");

        var item = await podio.ItemService.GetItem(1124848809);
        Console.WriteLine(item.Fields.Count);
    }
```

Update 1:

Because `main` method is a sync method, I called `Wait()` method to make calling `Init` method synchronously inside `main` method. To make things work correctly [never](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) define an async method with `void` return value, I also changed the return value of Init into `Task`.

Comment: I got a red line under 'Wait' - "Task does not contain a definition for Wait"

Comment: And for some reason it says that "The return type of async must be void". I am using visual studio.

Comment: Oh, it says async methods must return void OR Tasks. But neither of them are working.

Comment: Did you reference `System.Threading.Tasks`? `using System.Threading.Tasks`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that as of version 7.1 you can now have async Main methods. This code worked for me:

```
        static async Task<int> Main()
        {
            var podio = new Podio(clientId, clientSecret);
            await podio.AuthenticateWithPassword(username, password);

            var item = await podio.ItemService.GetItem(1124848809);
            Console.WriteLine(item.Fields.Count);

            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: I told you the problem related to the way how you calls the `async` method.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I marked your answer as accepted. This was my first question on here. Still learning the protocol. Thanks again!

Comment: It's ok @Xiolin, Stackoverlow is the home of the programmers. Make yourself comfortable